# Wrong image/link relative paths in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to load a page in my domain and then analyze the content of the page (getting the text/image/etc. and their positions). I tried my code on 2-3 different domains and it works fine. Only on one of the domains, when I am loading my page "subdomain.domain.com/page", selenium uses a wrong base url and load all the relative paths in a wrong way. For instance, instead of loading the following image:

```
subdomain.domain.com/my_image.jpg
```

it tries to load this path, and it clearly fails:

```
subdomain.domain.com/page/my_image.jpg
```

I first employed Selenium and PhantomJS and saw the issue. Then, I switched to Firefox on Xvfb and Selenium, but I still see the same issue. Here is how I load the page:

```
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("/usr/bin/firefox"));
binary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY",System.getProperty("lmportal.xvfb.id",":10"));
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", userAgent);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary,null);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(url);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where was the issue. I was adding a '/' at the end of the urls. Apparently, it messes up those relative paths. Thus, to solve this issue you may load:

```
subdomain.domain.com/page
```

instead of:

```
subdomain.domain.com/page/
```

Comment: Please don't forget to come back and mark this answer as accepted so the question will be marked as answered. Thanks!